# Java: Divide string

Tags: java, string, split

i have the following string: `String date = "01/03/2010";`
How to split this string to get separately the date,time and year?
i want something like this

```
String date = "1/3/2010";

int date = 1
int month = 3
int year = 2010
```

Comment: You tagged this question `split`. What method of the `String` class do you think you should use?

Comment: i dont know how to do it

Comment: Google: "Java split string" :D

Comment: There's two parts needed to get where you want. Look at the `String.split()` method and `Integer.parseInt`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to split a string in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3481828/how-to-split-a-string-in-java)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
String string = "1/3/2010";
String[] parts = string.split("/");
String part1 = parts[0]; // 1
String part2 = parts[1]; //3
String part2 = parts[2]; //2010
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [modern date-time API](https://www.oracle.com/technical-resources/articles/java/jf14-date-time.html) as shown below:

```
import java.time.LocalDate;
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String dateString = "01/03/2010";
        LocalDate date = LocalDate.parse(dateString, DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd/MM/yyyy"));
        int day = date.getDayOfMonth();
        int month = date.getMonthValue();
        int year = date.getYear();
        System.out.println("Day: " + day + ", Month: " + month + ", Year: " + year);
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
Day: 1, Month: 3, Year: 2010
```

Learn more about the modern date-time API at **[Trail: Date Time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/index.html)**.

Answer (score 0):

```java
String dateString = "01/03/2010";
DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd/MM/yyyy");
LocalDate localDate = LocalDate.parse(dateString, formatter);

int date = localDate.getDayOfMonth();
int month = localDate.getMonthValue();
int year = localDate.getYear();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `LocalDate` instead of splitting the `String`.

```
String date = "1/3/2010";

// create a pattern that matches your date format
DateTimeFormatter pattern = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("d/M/yyyy");

LocalDate parsed = LocalDate.parse(date, pattern);
```

You can then obtain various fields of the parsed `LocalDate`.

```
parsed.getDayOfMonth(); // 1
parsed.getMonthValue(); // 3
parsed.getYear());      // 2020
```